# Does all programs in Ubuntu are portable?

Tags: portable

I moved from windows to Ubuntu and I'm trying to understand if all the prgrams in Ubuntu are portable?

In Windows, you can use a regular program which spread it's files all over the FS, writes to the registry and has an entry in the add/remove menu, or you can use a portable program which store all it's data and files in one folder.

so,for example, it I want to have two different versions of Eclipse, that wasn't a problem in Windows because Eclipse is a portable application, but in Ubuntu I got Eclipse by apt-get, and in it there is only one version I can manage. So how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an application is portable or not depends on the way it was packed or distributed. Normally, you can install different version of applications via apt-get (ubuntu repos) and they'll co-exists, if they can't, you will be notified when installing the second one that you must remove the first in order to install the second. Packets installed via apt-get normally store their binaries in /usr/bin and their configuration files on hidden folders (folders starting with a dot) on your home directory, you can see them by pressing `ctrl-h` in the file manager while in your home dir.

If we go to the specific case of eclipse, you can do it as you do in windows, you can always download eclipse from their site (NOT from ubuntu repos) and keep it in a folder and it will store all of its config and data inside that folder.

check out the download page of eclipse (for linux)

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

It will download a compressed folder which you decompress and can directly execute the binary file inside the folder.

Answer (score 0):

İf you download tar.gz packages of program , this is portable.

1. download tar.gz
2. excract tar.gz
3. find program file ( etc. android)
4. and open it .